# Is there a way to plot a heatmap for a dataframe based on rows/columns?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I wanted to ask if anyone has ever done a heatmap on a Pandas DataFrame but on each individual columns (with the same color gradient showing 'low' to 'high'). It's more like the conditional formatting on each column in Excel (refer to the included image). I tried `sns.heatmap`, but it kind of gives the overall picture. I have a DataFrame like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0.1, 100, size = 30).reshape(5,6),
columns= ['A','B','C','D','E','F'], index = ['aa','bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'])
```

I wanted to make something like this.

[image: Example.jpg]

Comment: Plotly is a great library in python to do cool data visualization check it out they have heat maps and much more (https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick using `seaborn.heatmap` is to apply a [min-max normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) to each column of your DataFrame, so that the values of each column are rescaled to the range [0, 1].

[image]

The rescaled values are used to map the colors, but you annotate the heatmap with the original values (i.e., pass `annot=df`).

```
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = 30).reshape(5,6),
columns= ['A','B','C','D','E','F'], index = ['aa','bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee'])

norm_df = (df - df.min(0)) / (df.max(0) - df.min(0))

sns.heatmap(norm_df, annot=df, cmap="YlGn", cbar=False, lw=0.01)
```

**Output**

[image]